# Show Maxres or High Thumbnails using YouTube API

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, youtube-api, alamofire

I'm creating an app for my YouTube channel using the YouTube API. Some of my videos have a maxres thumbnail, but some of them don't. If a video appears in the tableview that I'm showing them in, and doesn't have a maxres thumbnail, the app crashes. I want to tell the API to use the maxres thumbnails if there are a maxres thumbnail for that video, but if there isn't, then just use the high one. This is my code.

```
Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search", parameters: ["part":"snippet","maxResults":50,"channelId":CHANNEL_ID,"playlistId":UPLOADS_PLAYLIST_ID,"q":searchText,"type":"video","key":API_KEY], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in

            if let JSON = response.result.value {

                if let dictionary = JSON as? [String: Any] {

                    var arrayOfVideos = [Video]()

                    guard let items = dictionary["items"] as? NSArray else { return }

                    for items in dictionary["items"] as! NSArray {
                        print("//Printing Video\n\(items)")
                        //  Create video objects off of the JSON response

                        let videoObj = Video()
                        videoObj.videoID = (items as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "id.videoId") as! String
                        videoObj.videoTitle = (items as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "snippet.title") as! String
                        videoObj.videoDescription = (items as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "snippet.description") as! String
                        videoObj.videoThumbnailUrl = (items as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url") as! String // Here I need to tell the API to use the maxres thumbnail if there is one.

                        arrayOfVideos.append(videoObj)

                    }
```

It seems like the API is not even looking for a maxres thumbnail. It only shows high, medium, and default. Whenever I use playlistItems, though, it does show the maxres thumbnails. Hmmmm...

Answer (score 1):

You should **never** unwrap web-based data implicitly. Always use `?` instead of `!`.

For the thumbnail, you should check whether a maxres thumbnail exists and if it's not available, use the default instead.

```
if let thumbnailUrl = (items as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url") as? String ?? (items as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "snippet.thumbnails.default.url") as? String {
    videoObj.videoThumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. I replaced                         `videoObj.videoThumbnailUrl = (items as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url") as! String` with the code you provided. It's just showing the default thumbnails on videos that do have a maxres. It seems like the API is not calling the maxres. In the terminal, it only shows high, medium, and default. There is a maxres option though, whenever I'm using the playlistItems. Hmmmm...

Answer (score 0):

I made this page for looking at [thumbnails](http://www.myonlinelocation.com/YouTube_Play/VideoThumbnails/?VideoID=M7lc1UVf-VE&url_base=i3.ytimg.com) as their URL's are simple and no api required. Just their video ID.
As to "wep" or "jpg", is all the same. Just platform specific.

What you will need to decide is do you really need a high res image, as size will impact loading time. You will also need to resize the image to fit into your thumbnail sizing.